# How can I resize hash table in python?

Tags: python, hashtable

I am trying to implement hash table in python. I am struggling resizing hash table in case there is duplicate address or hash table is too small.

This is my constructor,

```
def __init__(self):
    self.table_size = [11, 23, 47, 97, 197, 397, 797, 1597, 3203, 6421,
                      12853,
                  25717, 51437, 102877, 205759, 411527, 823117, 1646237,
                  3292489, 6584983, 13169977, 26339969, 52679969,
                  105359939, 210719881, 421439783, 842879579, 1685759167]
    self.table_size_index = 0
    self.counter = 0
    self.size = self.table_size[self.table_size_index]
    self.slot = [None] * self.size
    self.data = [None] * self.size
```

`table_size` contains enough prime numbers to create big hash table.
`table_size_index` indicates what table size I am using.

My `put` function is,

```
 def put(self, key, val):
        hash_value  = self.hash_function(key, len(self.slot))
        if self.slot[hash_value] == None:
            self.slot[hash_value] = key
            self.data[hash_value] = val
            #self.counter += 1
        else:

            if self.table_size_index < len(self.table_size) -1 :
                self.table_size_index += 1
                new_slot = [None] * self.table_size[self.table_size_index]
                new_data = [None] * self.table_size[self.table_size_index]

                # copying old hash table to new hash table
                for i in self.slot:
                    new_hash_value = self.hash_function(i, len(new_slot))
                    new_slot[new_hash_value] = i
                    temp = self.slot.index(i)
                    new_data[new_hash_value] = self.data[temp]
                self.slot = new_slot
                self.data = new_data
```

It always prints out `11` length of `slot` and `data`. If the key already exist, it does not increase its size. How can I fix this one?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a problem for your debugger. You need to figure out on your own that you never updated self.size, but beyond that I see a bunch of problems. Are you going to grow indefinitely until you have no hash collisions? Typically you want to implement one of two strategies for handling collisions, and only grow the table size if the actual number of entries gets over a certain percentage of the hash table size. Also you have other bugs. Also provide [mcve] as described in that help link.

Comment: the `data` is redundant,and the statement under `else` never excute,add a print to test it.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Do you mean that I have to use all slots first by open addressing then increase its size?

Comment: @obgnaw I will try. Thank you for checking!

Comment: All slots? No, that would be crazy. Look up hash table.